# Find out population growth and present in the following table R language

Tags: r, xls

I am working with the `urbanpop.xls` dataset; it contains urban population metrics for practically all countries in the world throughout time (source file in attachments). It contains three sheets for three different time periods. In each sheet, the first row contains the column names. Now I need to find out population growth in percentage. Please help me solve the problems that are on the image:

[image]

Comment: You are going to need to give us an MCVE and show us what you have so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear, you have to calculate `Growth(i) = Population(i)/Population(i-1)-1`

Comment: I've added a photo with a task, can look at it ?

Comment: Begin with downloading the table of every sheet and using cbind() to bind them one besides other

Comment: thanks, i did it, i stopped on the third question, dont know how to do it

Comment: please can you solve me the third problem, its urgent

Comment: Traspose using t() and then use the function diff()